# Inheritance in JointJS for Element?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5, jointjs

I am trying to build application based on JointJS and Angular 5. I am trying to create element with ports using `joint.shapes.devs.Model`. The main problem is with extending. I need to create basic class of the element and then inherit it in sub classes. 
When i am using `define`, for example: `BasicElement = joint.shapes.devs.Model.define(...)` and then i am trying to extend it with `SomeElement = BasicElement .define(...)` i am getting a TypeScript error `Property 'define' does not exist on type 'Constructor<Element>'.`

I also tried to make it in class-oriented way and then extends it like:

```
class BasicElement extends joint.shapes.devs.Model {
  markup = <g class="scalable">
        <rect class="body"/>
    </g>;
  inPorts =  ['in'],
  ports = { ... }
}
```

But it didn't work. How could i achieve class-oriented inheritance for element with ports? Thank you

Comment: were you able to solve this?